# Using turtle's onclick in a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, onclick, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to create a simple interface from a `dict` of strings inside a function. Each string is used to display text, and a clickable turtle (using `onclick()` to make the turtle clickable). This is so I can click on the turtle, and input some values.

But, if I understand it right, when the function finishes running the loop through the dictionary, all the varibles that the loop was supposed to define are redefined as the last one that passed trough the loop, the last element of the dictionary. So the `onclick()` function returns me only the last element of the dictionary.

Is there a way I could make one `onclick()` function react/correspond diferently to each element of the dictionary?  I really don't want to write a bunch of `onclick()` functions for every element of the dictionary.  I'm trying to learn a better way.

```
list_alunos={'joao': ['5', 'm'],'maria': ['5', 'm'],'lobo': ['5', 'm'],'mau': ['5', 'm']}
def caca(dictx,file):
    import turtle
    mes=file
    vert=350
    hor=-600


    def got(t,x,y,d) :
        t.penup()
        t.goto(x,y)
        t.pendown()
        t.seth(d)

    def text(t,text, size, color, pos1, pos2):
        t.penup()
        t.goto(pos1, pos2)
        t.color(color)
        t.begin_fill()
        t.write(text, font=('Arial', size, 'normal'))
        t.end_fill()




    new_vert = vert
    for key in dictx:
        nome = key
        if vert == -340:
            new_vert = 350
            new_hor = hor + 250
        if vert!= -340:
            new_vert= new_vert-30
            new_hor = hor
            txt_vert = new_vert - 15
            txt_hor = new_hor + 20

        screen = turtle.Screen()

        width = 1200
        height = 1500
        turtle.screensize(width, height)



        tnome = turtle.Turtle(shape='turtle')
        tnome.color('pink')
        textnome = turtle
        tnome.speed('fastest')
        textnome.speed('fastest')

        text(textnome, '%s' %(nome), '20', 'pink', txt_hor,txt_vert)

        got(tnome,new_hor,new_vert,0)
        def tnome_handler(x, y):

            pos = list(dictx.keys()).index(nome)
            listt = list(dictx)

            pnt = screen.textinput(' pontuação', '%s:  '%(listt[pos]))
            pnt = [int(x) for x in pnt.split()]
            if len(pnt) == 5 :
                with open('%s.py' %(mes), 'a') as fd:
                    fd.write('\n%s.pontuacao(%i,%i,%i,%i,%i)' % (nome,pnt[0],pnt[1],pnt[2],pnt[3],pnt[4]))
                tnome.color('blue')
        tnome.onclick(tnome_handler)


caca(list_alunos,'mm')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive the following rework of your code does what you desire.  It effectively generates a custom handler for each turtle/button that responds uniquely to it:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 1200, 1500

dict_alunos = {'joao': ['5', 'm'], 'maria': ['5', 'm'], 'lobo': ['5', 'm'], 'mau': ['5', 'm']}

def text(t, text, size, color, x, y):
    t.penup()
    t.goto(x + size, y - size/2)
    t.color(color)
    t.write(text, align='left', font=('Arial', str(size), 'normal'))
    t.goto(x, y)

def caca(dictionary, mes):

    def tnome_handler(nome, turtle, x, y):

        pnt = screen.textinput('pontuação', '%s:  ' % (nome))
        pnt = [int(x) for x in pnt.split()]

        if len(pnt) == 5:
            with open('%s.py' % (mes), 'a') as fd:
                fd.write('s.pontuacao(%i, %i, %i, %i, %i)\n' % (nome, pnt[0], pnt[1], pnt[2], pnt[3], pnt[4]))

        turtle.color('blue')

    vert = 350
    hor = -600

    new_vert = vert

    for nome in dictionary:

        if vert == -340:
            new_vert = 350
            new_hor = hor + 250

        if vert != -340:
            new_vert = new_vert - 30
            new_hor = hor
            txt_vert = new_vert - 15
            txt_hor = new_hor + 20

        turtle = Turtle(shape='turtle')
        turtle.color('pink')
        turtle.speed('fastest')
        turtle.setheading(0)

        text(turtle, '%s' % (nome), 20, 'pink', txt_hor, txt_vert)

        turtle.onclick(lambda x, y, n=nome, t=turtle: tnome_handler(n, t, x, y))

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(WIDTH, HEIGHT)

caca(dict_alunos, 'mm')

screen.mainloop()
```

I've also reworked the code to fit a more common programming design.